# What is the optimal position for a right click menu?

Tags: placement, contextual-menu, mouse, right-click

We're in the middle of designing a web application with a right click menu, and I was thinking where to position it relative to the position of the cursor.

There are different solutions:

[image]

Solution 1 is the standard in OS X and Microsoft Windows. But which solution do you prefer, and why?

Comment: It should be noticed that solution 1 is only the standard, if your cursor is high enough -- otherwise, solution four is the one used. In Windows, at least, the same is not true if your cursor goes too far right. Try that one out for yourself -- it's interesting.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**1. Is the standard for both Windows and OSX. You should go with this.**

*Update: (Note that when clicking at extreme bottom of screen it will automatically display as 4,when at extreme right it will display as 3, and at extreme bottom right it displays as 2.)*

This seems to make sense, you right click, and are at the top left position of the list of options. Usually when you get a list, you will want to start from the top.

Comment: 4 is also standard if you are low enough on the screen that the menu will not fit below the cursor.

Comment: Good point Charles. 3 is also standard for being all the way to the right when it won't fit.

Comment: Thank you for confriming what I thought. I think 1st is the best as well. On the other hand I saw 3. in Win7, that was the main reason for asking.

Comment: @Roland - where did you see #3? I have never seen that in Windows 7

Comment: @Charles - Right clicking in the extreme right area.

Comment: Try going most of the way to the right or left (in windows). The solution is actually none of these. The context menu is pushed all the way to the right of the screen. So it's not really #2 or #3 at any point, only #1 and #4 modified -- which, on the extreme right end, equates to solutions #2 and #3.

Comment: @Charles - I will get a screenshot of this option (one of my colleagues showed me)

Comment: here's a Win7 screenshot from my colleague: http://bit.ly/pc2ihu

Answer (score 4):

The optimal position is #1, the top left corner, for text that reads left to right and top to bottom. This positioning allows for the text to be easily read and for the user to move the mouse and their eyes in the same direction that they normally read.

But when the mouse is positioned close to the edge of the viewport the panel should be displayed so as not to be hidden or trigger scrolling.

[image]

If the mouse is close to the bottom left of the viewport the panel should be displayed above the mouse as in your #4 example.

[image]

When the mouse is close to the bottom right it would resemble #2.

[image]

If the mouse is to the right and is far enough above the bottom of the viewport for the panel to be displayed example #3 would be used.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Interestingly, from the Fitts' Law point of view, the optimal one would be

[image]

which reduces the mean distance to target to half.

Well, the **really** optimal would be one where the cursor is already on top of an option, but that's not going to end well.

Comment: Why would it not end well if the cursor was already on top of the most commonly used item?

Comment: Well, action menus don't usually come with a pre-selected option. Navigation menus might, but action menus don't - as a rule. In most cases it's pretty difficult to know with confidence what's the most commonly used item. And even if we did, it's just too error-inducing. It may be wrongly interpreted as a default or a system recommendation.

Comment: The really, *really* optimal position is a **pie menu**, with each option radiating out from the center. Which raises the question, [Are radial contextual menus better than vertical list menus?](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1/are-radial-contextual-menus-better-than-vertical-list-menus)

Comment: The default option can be based off of the user's usage patterns. It doesn't have to be a system recommendation that's absolute for everyone. A good analogy is Firefox's address bar. It counts the number of times particular keywords you type lead to particular links. It will place *your* most common links per that keyword on top of the list.

Answer (score 0):

I like (4), because it's the least biomechanically arduous (whether you are making the gesture with a mouse or trackpad).

Granted, if there established ways of doing this (as other commenters have suggested), then it probably makes sense to go with those, because that's what people are used to, and it will speed up their workflow accordingly.

Comment: All 4 options put the cursor hotspot in one of the corners so the distance to each element is the same on average. Am I missing something that would make option 4 better?

Comment: Well, this might just be my take on it :o) but if you're right-handed, as 90% of people are, try moving your mouse/trackpad hand on the upwards-and-right diagonal, as though you were moving the cursor between 3 and 2 on the grid shown above). Now try making the opposite diagonal movement, as though to trace between 4 and 1 on the grid. See how the first diagonal only requires a tiny movement in your wrist, compared to the other diagonal, which requires you to move your whole arm?

Answer (score 0):

(1) does not cover the element / line you just clicked on, and does not cover the start of the next line / element.

This preserves most relevant context to make a decision while the popup is covering the document.

"next line" rationale: because it might contain relevant information too, and the most important of that (such as name/title) is usually at the beginning of the line.

Specifically I *hate* hover popups that cover the current/next line. When scanning a list sequentially, this blocks the current or next item, so much of mouse waving is involved.